# Custom setter for @property?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can i use a custom setter  for the following property after I synthesized it ?

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIButton *but
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
@property (getter=yourGetter,setter=yourSetter:) UIButton *but;
```

Comment: Also note as Sascha pointed out, if you provide a custom setter, you are expected to release/retain the references yourself.

Comment: Note that custom getter and setter is like normal SELECTOR, so yourSetter: must have trailing colon

Answer (score 23):

@Sascha is almost right but his code has a tiny bug in it ;)

It would look like either :

A)

```
-(void)setBut:(UIButton *)value {
    if (but != value) {
        [but release];
        but = [value retain];
    }
}
```

or B)

```
-(void)setBut:(UIButton *)value {
    [but autorelease];
    but = [value retain];
}
```

(A) is (very) slightly more efficient, (B) is more readable.

---

Why do we need the if statement in option (A) instead of just the release & retain in @Sascha's answer?

What happens if you pass in the same object twice?

i.e.

```
// We set our button for the first time
UIButton *test = [UIButton alloc] init];
[self setBut:test];
[test release];


// Much later in the code, we set the button again
[self setBut:test];
```

If we didn't check that `but` wasn't a different object, the first thing we would do in our setter is `release` it. We would then try to `retain` an object that doesn't exist anymore, causing a crash.

NB We don't need the if statement in option (B) because autorelease won't immediately release the button so we have time to retain it again without it being dealloc'd.

Answer (score 1):

A B+) alternative to deanWombourne solutions:

```
-(void)setBut:(UIButton *)value {
    [value retain]
    [but release];
    but = value;
}
```

This solution will prevent issues where *value* is a sub-object of *but*.

An A+) alternative to deanWombourne solutions:

```
-(void)setBut:(UIButton *)value {
    if (but != value) {
        [value retain]
        //insert here but's cancel, invalidate, delegate = nil, ...
        [but release];
        but = value;
    }
}
```

This solution will prevent issues where *value* is a sub-object of *but*.
And it will allow you to add a `cancel` for an NSURLConnection, an `invalidate` an NSTimer or NSPort, a nil for a delegate, ...

Answer (score 0):

Implement

```
- (void)setBut:(UIButton *)aButton;
```

It should probably look something like

```
- (void)setBut:(UIButton *)aButton {
    [but release];
    but = [aButton retain];
    // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is how the @synthesised setters do it, and it works in all situations, regardless of whether you assign the same object or not:

```
- (void)setBut: (UIButton*)aButton
{
    id oldObject = but;
    but = [aButton retain];
    [oldObject release];
}
```

Cannot go wrong, as far as I can see.