# Save and segue UIImageView after moving with UIPanGestureRecognizer. Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uipangesturerecognizer

Good day.

This is my last option — to ask here.

The problem is: I am building multiply view app. On the first screen I have `UIImageView` that I can move with `UIPanGestureRecognizer` function:

```
@IBAction func movement(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)

    if let view = recognizer.view {

        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x, y:view.center.y + translation.y)

    }

    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

It's a usual code to move things around, I took at [raywenderlich.com](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial)

So what I want is to save position of the `UIImageView` element after interaction with it and after segue.

I believe that I need to return `CGPoint` from this function and segue it like so:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showPlaylistDetail" {
            let playlistDetailController = segue.destinationViewController as! PlaylistDetailViewController

playlistDetailController.image2.center = image1.center

        }
    }
```

So my question(s) is(are):

1. Do I use right code to move an object with Pan Gesture Recognizer?
2. How would you return `CGPoint` from this function and how would you read it?
3. How would I save UIImageView's position in process of segue and after?

*huh... This little bug is killing me. I bet, it is easy to solve, but as far as I am beginner I have no idea how :(*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description there are several solutions, my would be.

maintain a property `currentCenter` in the `firstViewController`

```
var currentCenter:CGPoint
```

In method `movement` add the following line after setting `view.center`

```
currentCenter.x = view.center.x
currentCenter.y = view.center.y
```

and then `prepareForSegue` as you said.

Hope this approach helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it does not seems right. As I get from this answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014800/property-synthesize-equivalent-in-swift ) there is no @property in Swift. So do you suggest to use global variable?

Comment: yes, and If you have a single `imageView` that you are moving, you can directly pass `thatImageView.center`.

Comment: It does not work. Image comes right to it's initial position after segue starts.

Comment: you need to use same approach. declare a variable in second view controller. in your `prepareForSegue` assign `currentCenter` to that variable. and In `viewDidLoad` in second view controller assign the variable to `imageview.center`.