# @property @synthesize equivalent in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have something like

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *whiteBfFillUp;
@end

@synthesize locationManager;
```

I am new to swift coding. Can anyone tell me the equivalent code in swift.

Comment: What are your learning resources for Objective-C? They seem to be outdated, as `@synthesize` is not needed since about 2012. Also `strong` should be used instead of `retain`.

Comment: var whiteBfFillUp: UIImageView?

Comment: Yeah this is not Modern Objective-c. Now-a-days `@synthesize` is done automatically for you. but The swift equivalent of that would be what @Vladimir S said.

Comment: This piece of code was written long ago.Anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@property/@synthesize equivalent in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014800/property-synthesize-equivalent-in-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent.
In Swift when you write a `var`or `let` in a class or struct declaration you already declaring a property.

> Define properties to store values

This is what is written in Swift documentation.
If you are concerned about access control you can use `private` or `public` modifiers.

```
public var somePublicVariable = 0
```

If you'd like to override properties such as you did in Objective-C you will find useful properties observers such as `didSet{}` `willSet{}`.

If you need a a readonly properties you can make the setter private.

```
public private(set) var hours = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for equivalent of property, then you just need to create your class level variables. All class level variables are by default 'strong' or 'retain'. If, however, you want them to be weak then use `weak`.

This would  be something like

`var whiteBfFillUp: UIImageView? = nil`

The `?` at the end means that this is an optional type. If it's not, you would need to assign it some value in the init method, or right there.