# Is there a way to override "property" setters and getters in Swift?

Tags: swift, properties, objective-c-swift-bridge

After reading *[@property/@synthesize equivalent in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014800/property-synthesize-equivalent-in-swift)*, I became curious for how the functionality from Objective C was retained.

Say I have the following in Objective C:

```objective-c
@interface MyClass
@property (readwrite) MyType *myVar;
@end
```

This can be accessed like such with dot- and smalltalk-based syntaxes:

```objective-c
Type *newVar1 = myClassInstance.myVar;
Type *newVar2 = [myClassInstance myVar];

myClassInstance.myVar = newVar1;
[myClassInstance setMyVar: newVar2];
```

And if I want to add some additional functionality to those getters/setters, I can do this:

```
@implementation MyClass

- (MyType *) myVar
{
    // do more stuff
    return self._myVar;
}

- (void) setMyVar: (MyType *) newVar
{
    self._myVar = newVar;
    // do more stuff
}

@end
```

<sub>(see also *[Custom setter for @property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843125/custom-setter-for-property)*)</sub>

However, [the accepted answer to the above linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24014922/4479896) says that Swift doesn't differentiate between properties and instance variable. So, say I have the following in Swift:

```
class MyClass {
    var myVar: MyType
}
```

As far as I know, the only way to access `myVar` is as such:

```
var newVar1 = myClassInstance.myVar;

myClassInstance.myVar = newVar1;
```

But I don't know how to customize these getters and setters. **Is there a Swift equivalent of the Objective C `@property` overrides?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While researching this question, I actually happened upon my answer, but still figured it should be put here for anyone else with the same question.

---

Yes, according to [the Swift Programming Language documentation's page on Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID260), getters and setters can be made in a similar way to how C# tackles the problem:

```swift
struct MyParentType {
    var myPlainVar: MyType = MyType()
    
    var myCustomGetterVar: MyType {
        // do more stuff
        return self.myCustomGetterVar
    }
    
    var myCustomGetterSetterVar: MyType {
        get {
            // do more stuff
            return self.myCustomGetterSetterVar
        }
        set {
            // do stuff
            self.myCustomGetterSetterVar = newValue
            // do more stuff
        }
    }
    
    var myCustomFancyVar: MyType? {
        willSet {
            // do stuff with newValue
        }
        // actual setting is done automatically, so no set{}
        didSet {
            // do more stuff with oldValue
        }
    }
}
```

Note that variables with `didSet` must be initialized or optional, and cannot have a `get`, since properties which are computed with `get` can easily implement their own `didSet` and `willSet` if they so choose.

Comment: You're a bit mixed up when it comes to `willSet`/`didSet`.  The `!` you're using is not an unpacking operator – you're declaring `myCustomFancyVar` to be an "implicitly unwrapped optional" i.e. a variable that can have a `nil` value. Since these don't have to be initialized (they default to `nil`), you don't have to give it a default value. But if you gave it an initial value or used an initializer, you would not need the `!`: `struct S { var x: Int = 1 { willSet(newVal) { println("willSet: \(newVal)") }
 didSet { println("did set") } } }; var s = S(x: 5); s.x = 2`